# Circular navigation in navcontroller

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am having ListFragment, DetailFragment and OperationFragemnt. My ListFragment has the data list in Bundle object so it is always there when I am navigating from DetailFragment to ListFragment using

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

In OperationFragment my app is speaking with backend server and based on response I am trying to take user ListFragment using `setFragmentResult` [as per the doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate) but can not get the `setFragmentResultListener` working

in OperationFragment

```
val resultToBeSent = "result"
parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResult("requestKey", bundleOf("bundleKey" to resultToBeSent))
```

in DetailFragment

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Use the Kotlin extension in the fragment-ktx artifact
    parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener("requestKey",this) { requestKey, bundle ->
   // We use a String here, but any type that can be put in a Bundle is supported
   val result = bundle.getString("bundleKey")
   // Do something with the result
   findNavController().popBackStack()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result comes from the child fragment, everything else are `NavArgs` (there's two directions).

```
getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("request_key", bundle)
```

Not sure if `.popBackStack()` may interfere. I use `<dialog/>` and `dismiss()`. I mean, the result already arrives before navigating. You cannot set `this` as listenener unless implementing `interface` [`FragmentResultListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentResultListener):

```
/** Callback used to handle results passed between fragments. */
public fun onFragmentResult(requestKey: String, result: Bundle) {
    if (requestKey.equals("request_key")) {
        result.getString("bundle_key")
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying popBackStack from OperationFragement, and then DetailFragment. If I use findNavController().navigate(R.id.operationFragmentToListFragment) then it is creating new instance of ListFragment. I am just trying to popbackstack sequentialy

Comment: Enable debug output: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager#enableDebugLogging(boolean) ...one can also obtain results with `NavBackStackEntry`, `LifecycleEventObserver` and `SavedStateHandle` - but only `FragmentResultListener` needs to be implemented.